# Scanner input values are not all being stored

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner which reads in strings as coordinate inputs. I have to convert these strings into integers and store them in an Arraylist of coordinates but the last values I input are not being stored in the arraylist.

I have tried using the `startEndLineScan.nextLine();` outside the for-loop but still no change I have also tried using a while loop instead of a for loop when storing and parsing the strings but I get the same results.

```
ArrayList<Integer> convertedCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String samplePointsCoords[];
Scanner startEndLineScan = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 1;
while (startEndLineScan.hasNextLine()) {
    startEndPointsInputs = startEndLineScan.nextLine();
    samplePointsCoords = startEndPointsInputs.split(",");
    if (count < 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < samplePointsCoords.length; ++i) {
            convertedCoords.add(Integer.parseInt(samplePointsCoords[i]));
        }
        count++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print("Points: " + convertedCoords)
```

Input:

```
1,2
3,4
```

Expected results:
Points: [1,2,3,4]

Actual Results
Points: [1,2]

Comment: `if (count < 2)` ?

Comment: `count = 1` then `if (count < 2)`? This only iterates once

Comment: I have set the count to 0 yet I still get the same result

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> convertedCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String samplePointsCoords[];
Scanner startEndLineScan = new Scanner(System.in);
int count;
while (startEndLineScan.hasNextLine()) {
    count = 1;
    startEndPointsInputs = startEndLineScan.nextLine();
    samplePointsCoords = startEndPointsInputs.split(",");
    if (count < 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < samplePointsCoords.length; ++i) {
            convertedCoords.add(Integer.parseInt(samplePointsCoords[i]));
        }
        count++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print("Points: " + convertedCoords)
```

Notice `int count;` is declared and reinitialized at the start of every loop
This will fix your code but you should really try to understand what you are writing! cheers.